# what's the point of using scanners in java (android)

Tags: java, android, java.util.scanner

Let me explain in detail, I kept googling about scanners and I can't fully understand what are scanners exactly.
I read many articles but all of them say

> The java.util.Scanner class is a simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and
>   strings using regular expressions

quoted from the official website, most websites took it and non of them said what a scanner is in english

Let me illustrate.

I have 3 views, a `Button`, `EditText`,`TextView`. I wanted to take the text from the `EditView` and put it in the `TextView` and I have 2 approaches, my question is what is the difference between them.

ALL THIS CODE GOES INTO THE ONCLICK LISTENER.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(editText.getText().toString());
 String a = sc.next();
 txv.setText(a);
```

and this 
`txv.setText(editText.getText().toString());`

I got the data and it worked exactly the same in both cases and I can't seem to find anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using Scanner here, you should be using StringTokenizer, or just `split("\\s+")[0]` on the string.

But `sc.next()` will read the first consecutive non-whitespace characters of the Scanner's input string into the variable `a`, which gets set to the next textview.

For example

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("hello world");
String s = sc.next(); // == "hello"
```

---

Otherwise, in CLI applications Scanner is used for interactive inputs. Doesn't have much other use cases in production code that I can think of. Even for reading files, BufferedReader or the NIO API would be preferred

Comment: That last paragraph is the key here!

Comment: that white-space sentence made me understand everything, It didn't move the spaces as expected after reading your reply. Appreciated